# How to get "Correct uv" to work on popup menu

Tags: mesh, scripting, 3d-view

I want to have the "correct uv" command on a popup menu, but according to the programmer i am using at the time the the "Correct uv" can't be overided. I want to be able to check that box so that the next time when i slide a vert the function is activated. Is this possible to do?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where is this "Correct UV" menu option? I don't recognize the Material Menu in your screen shot.

Comment: The material Menu you see in my screenshot is custom. In Blender the default place for this function is the "t" panel. It gets visible down on the panel after you have used "vertex slide" command.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to know how to enable that option by default I think I can answer that. But I'm curious, how did you make this custom menu? Because I'm not sure if enabling it by default for the keyboard shortcut will also make it default in your menu.

Comment: The idea is not to have it enabled by default,it's  i to be able to  activate/deactivate throught my own menu,not the default placement in Blender, that was my original question. My meny pops up inside a pie menu i have.

Comment: Hmmm. Well in that case I'm not sure I can answer. But what do you mean by "inside a pie menu"?

Comment: the menu popup when you drag your mouse over a pie slot.

Comment: I guess you mean some kind of circular menu item. The only circular menu item I can think of is the Color Picker, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you are talking about. A Google Image Search for "pie slot" just shows slot machines and slices of pie, so at this point I'm lost. Good luck though.

Comment: no he means usgin the addon "pie menus", I guess. Enabling that, you get a "pie menu" with several commands, pressing Q, iirc

Answer (score 1):

Haven't had time to test this, the code comes from another answer.  Adds a menu label for each operator in the window_manager list of reg'd operators used.  The settings used for the **Edge Slide** operator are expanded. Added the `correct_uv` for you to test if changing the prop from the menu results in the behaviour you require.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

class SimpleCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Recently Run Operators"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_simple_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        wm = context.window_manager
        op = wm.last_edge_slide
        if op:        
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(wm, "set_correct_uv")
            row.prop(op, "correct_uv")
            layout.separator()
        # reverse order
        ops = [o for o in wm.operators]
        ops.reverse()
        for o in ops:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text=o.name)
            if o.name == 'Edge Slide':
                layout.separator()
                row = layout.row()
                row.label(text="bpy.ops.transform.edge_slide(%s)" % ", "
                         .join(["%s=%s" % (k, str(v)) 
                                for k, v in o.properties.items()]))
                for k, v in o.properties.items():
                    row = layout.row()
                    row.label(text="%s = %s" % (k, str(v))) 
                # draw the prop
                row = layout.row()
                row.prop(o, "correct_uv")       
                layout.separator()

def get_correct_uv(self):
    op = self.last_edge_slide
    if op:
        return op.correct_uv
    return False

def set_correct_uv(self, value): 
    op = self.last_edge_slide   
    if op:
        op.correct_uv = value
    return None

def get_last_edgeslide(self):
    ops = [o for o in self.operators if o.name.startswith("Edge Slide")]
    if len(ops):
        op = ops[-1]
        return op
    return None

def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.last_edge_slide = property(get_last_edgeslide)

    bpy.types.WindowManager.set_correct_uv = BoolProperty(get=get_correct_uv,
                                                             set=set_correct_uv,
                                                             name="Set Correct UV")

    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleCustomMenu) 


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleCustomMenu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

Narrow down the operator list above to the last occurrence of the Edge Slide operator, can also look at `context.active_operator`

[image]

Added a property on the window_manager with a getter and setter to emulate the operator property, and a `last_edge_slide` property on the window manager to return the last used edge slide op, or `None`.

Comment: Thanks alot for that answer! I need to get hold of the programmer that is helping me, i will get back to you if this works.

Comment: batFINGER, It does not work. I actually really didn't realize how wierd Blenders "correct uv" is by default. you can see that the checkbox are not checked in the the panel and yet it works all the time when you click "gg" really odd behaviour.